# I need to resize some digital artwork made in PS for print....?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design, resize

I have some graphics I worked on and posted to tumblr and a couple other social media sites, but now I have to print them, they're originally in 500px by 650px or 500px by 750px. Problem is when I try to print them on regular A4 size paper, they lose all sharpness and quality, the text becomes grainy and the images and accents all have a haze on them. I've worked out how to resize a few, and I have only a couple psd's of them since I made them originally for digital publishing and not print. So does anyone know a way around this? Printing, or resizing the image without losing it's quality or keeping sharpness. I'm still in college learning graphic design, and most of it's self taught for me, so please be kind, I don't know much, this is the first time I'm having to print my work out for show, rather than publish to online sources.

Comment: It's really hard to add resolution that's simply not there. There are some tools and plugins that can try and enlarge an image for you using fractals or vector tracing, and they can work in certain cases. But, for the most part, you simply need to start over and work at a higher resolution from the start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so generally speaking - something you uploaded for the web is 72 dpi, which when printed comes out low quality and pixelated, for print we use 240-300 dpi. This means the quantity of pixels in every inch, so when enlarging the dpi you will be force to make the image "smaller" in photoshop (then you change the resolution the size will change automatically.
In order to get the highest size possible, after changing the resolution to 300 dpi choose this:
[image]